# Subtract order quantity from available quantity in sql server get output like below

Tags: sql-server

Please click on link for output [Last two column is need output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvJlD.png)

Available qty - Orderqty = positive value

If positive value make green

After that remaining available is subtracted from second row and get the result 
A if positive result make green else yellow.

```
                                             output 
Date           Item OrderQty    AvailQty       A    B
12-Aug-16       A   10         50              40   Green
13-Aug-16       A   20         50              20   Green
14-Aug-16       A   30         50             -10   Yellow
15-Aug-16       B   40         30             -10   Yellow
16-Aug-16       B   50         30              0    Red
17-Aug-16       C   100        300             200  Green
18-Aug-16       C   170        300             30   green
19-Aug-16       C   40         300            -10   Yellow
20-Aug-16       C   30         300             0    Red
```

50-10=40       green

40-20=20       green

20-30=-10 then yellow

according item and date is asc

If finally available become zero then make it as  red

Please also check for attached image link https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvJlD.png

Thanks

Comment: please paste results/tables as text and also paste expected output,so that one will have chance to repro by copying

Answer (score 0):

```
*I used here cursor and temp table to to get the output y for yellow,R for Red and G for Green.

create table #test(
[Date] date,    
Item varchar(20),
OrderQty int,    
AvailQty int
)

insert into #test values

('2016-08-11',  'A',    10, 50),

('2016-08-12','A',  20, 50),

('2016-08-13','A',  30, 50),

('2016-08-12','B',  40, 30),

('2016-08-13','B',  50, 30),

('2016-08-13','C',  100,    300),

('2016-08-14','C',  170,    300),

('2016-08-15','C',  40, 300),

('2016-08-16','C',  30, 300)


Alter table #TEST 
Add id int identity(1,1)

--drop table #itemValue
create table #itemValue (item varchar(100),AvailValue int)

insert into #itemValue  select distinct item,AvailQty from #TEST

declare @item varchar(50)

declare @order int

declare @id int

declare curname cursor

Local scroll static

for

select Id,Item,OrderQty from #test

open curname

Fetch next from curname

into @id,@item,@order

declare @tem2 as int

print  cast(@id as varchar(1000))

set @tem2=(select AvailValue from #itemValue where item=@item)

--------------------------------------------------------------------
if(@tem2>@order )

begin

update #test set st='G' where Item=@item and id=@id

update #itemValue set AvailValue=AvailValue-@order where item=@item

end

else if(@tem2<@order) 

begin

update #test set st='Y' where Item=@item and id=@id

update #itemValue set AvailValue=0 where item=@item

end

else

begin

update #test set st='R' where Item=@item and id=@id

end
--------------------------------------------------------------------

while @@FETCH_STATUS=0

begin

declare @tem1 as int

print  cast(@id as varchar(1000))

print cast(@tem1 as varchar(100))

--update #itemValue set AvailValue=AvailValue-@order where item=@item

set @tem1=(select AvailValue from #itemValue where item=@item)

if(@tem1>@order )

begin

update #test set st='G' where Item=@item and id=@id

update #itemValue set AvailValue=AvailValue-@order where item=@item

end

else if(@tem1=0) 

begin

update #test set st='R' where Item=@item and id=@id

end

else if(@tem1<@order) 

begin

update #test set st='Y' where Item=@item and id=@id

update #itemValue set AvailValue=0 where item=@item

end

Fetch next from curname

into @id,@item,@order
--print  cast(@item as varchar(1000))
end*
```

Comment: Thank you very much quick answer.